# Reading pcap file using lua

Tags: networking, lua, wireshark, packet

I am very new in using lua. My area is to explore lua in wireshark. I have a captured pcap file. How can i open that file and read different things in different headers(like port numbers in tcp/udp headers, application related information in http header, etc).
I am very sorry this is a direct question, but i didn't have anything to refer to solve this. I can no where find examples sitng this information. Can you guys please atleast point in some direction/reference to make use of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Lua API in wireshark is very powerful. It can be used to write dissectors, post-dissectors and taps. You can start with the `Lua Support in Wireshark`
 in Wireshark software's help, or [Reference Manual](http://www.cse.sc.edu/~okeefe/tutorials/wireshark/wsluarm_modules.html). The wireshark official [Lua wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua) is also helpful. Note that some of the code example is out of date.

In your case, only analyzing pcap files is needed. There's another way to do so. `Tshark`, the Wireshark command tool, can be used to analyze the pcap file, and output the result to text files(or, if needed, xml formatted files). You can use `Lua` scripts to call `tshark` and process the result, like processing any text files.

Here's an example I wrote to analyze `Megaco` protocal in Windows. As you can see, other scripting languages can also be used in this way, especially `Perl`. But `Lua` code is clearly more elegant, and, in practice, more efficient.

```
local XmlFile = io.popen('"C:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\tshark"  -nn -r 3gpp_mc.cap -d udp.port==1001,megaco -T pdml ')
--local XmlFile = io.open("xmlexample.xml", "r")
local RawXml = XmlFile:read("*all")

local Megaco = {}
for m in string.gmatch(RawXml, '<proto name="megaco".-</proto>') do
    Megaco[#Megaco + 1] = m
end

local Item = {}
for i = 1, #Megaco do
    for p in string.gmatch(Megaco[i], 'show=(".-")') do
    print(p)
    end
end
XmlFile:close()
```

UPDATE:
The key is to use `tshark` to output the info you need and let `Lua` do the text processing. `Tshark` has a rich set of parameters for use, see [here](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) for detail. Here's how to call `tshark` in your need:

```
tshark -nn -r file.pcap -T fields -E separator=; -e frame.number -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e tcp.srcport -e tcp.dstport (tcp)
```

Comment: Here are some other links:
• Wireshark User's Guide: www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/wsluarm.html
• [Wireshark Wiki: Lua](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua)
• [Wireshark Wiki: Lua - Examples](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Examples)
• [Sharkfest09](http://sharkfest.wireshark.org/sharkfest.09/index.html) - Developer Track Presentations: presentation by Stig Bjorlykke about Lua Scripting In Wireshark

Comment: @Yu Hao  Can you please write small 2-3 lines script to open a packet and output, lets say src address, destination address in ip header and tcp src port and tcp destination port so that i can start from there. Thank u